# Only one marker shown when a list of markers is given to a google map flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, dart, mobile

I want to create a google map with multiple markers which are updates when the when the values of the database changes, The database changes do happen and can be seen in the front end but the problem is there should be two marker s but only one marker is shown.

```
class _UserHomeScreenState extends State<UserHomeScreen> {
  GoogleMapController? _controller;
  StreamedResponse? streamedResponse;
  StreamSubscription? subscription;
  httpService = HttpService();
  Map<int, LocationModel> onlineBus = {};
  Map<int, Marker> markers = {};
  Map<int, Circle> circles = {};

  static final CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(6.825763222842125, 79.93603206070449),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
```

Listening to the stream here no of online buses comes as 2.
And No of markers comes as 2

```
  void subscribeToStream() async {
    streamedResponse =
        await httpService.subscribe(UserPreference.getUserId().toString());
    subscription = streamedResponse!.stream
                  .toStringStream()
                  .asBroadcastStream()
                  .listen((event) async {
                  try {
                  LocationModel locationModel =     LocationModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(event));
    setState(() {
      onlineBus[locationModel.bus.id] = locationModel;
      updateMarkerAndCircle(onlineBus);
    });

    // Uint8List imageData = await getMarker();
    print('No of online buses----->${onlineBus.length}');
    print('No of online Markers----->${markers.length}');

    print(locationModel.bus.id);
  } catch (e) {}
});
 }
```

Method to update markers by iterrating through the list

```
 void updateMarkerAndCircle(Map<int, LocationModel> buses) {
    for (int i in buses.keys) {
      LatLng latlng = LatLng(buses[i]!.lat, buses[i]!.lon);
  setState(() {
    Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(buses[i]!.bus.route.routeId),
        position: latlng,
        rotation: buses[i]!.heading,
        draggable: false,
        zIndex: 2,
        flat: true,
        anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
            BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue));
        Circle circle = Circle(
        circleId: CircleId("car"),
        radius: buses[i]!.accuracy,
        zIndex: 1,
        strokeColor: Colors.blue,
        center: latlng,
        fillColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(70));

        markers[i] = marker;
       circles[i] = circle;
     });
   }
 }
```

Init state

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    subscribeToStream();
    super.initState();
 }
```

Build Method

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          onChanged: (value) {},
          decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Search'),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 700,
          child: GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
            markers: markers.values.toSet(),
            circles: circles.values.toSet(),
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller = controller;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```